# Find out plan estimate of user stories moved to next iteration in rally

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

Does anyone know how to use Rally **Web service APIs** to calculate the  total amount of accepted work delivered by the last day of the iteration and the total amount of accepted work delivered since the last day of the iteration.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find that information using the [Lookback API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/Analytics2.0LookbackAPIUserManual.html). Every time an artifact changes in Rally it takes a snapshot of that data. If you query that API for artifacts that have had their Schedule state changed during those time periods you will be able to gather the information you want.

Comment: Thanks Charles for your answer.. I actually wanted this data to create the velocity chart using the Rally Web Service API..Right now i'm getting the sum of all accepted US/defects and sum of all US/defects but not the US accepted in the current iteration and US accepted in the next iteration.. Any idea on how this can be achieved ?